# How to use your own id for Document in Spring Data Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a entity which has a unique string value that I would like to use instead of the auto-generated objectId in spring mongodb documents. However, when I save the object it still generates an ObjectId.  Here is the document.

```java
                   @Document(collection="products")
                   class Product {
                       
                       @Id 
                       @Indexed(unique = true,direction = IndexDirection.ASCENDING)
                       String productCode;
                       
                       String descr;
                                              
                       Integer quantity;   
                       
                       public Product(String productCode,String descr,Integer quantity)
                       {
                         this.productCode = productCode;
                         this.descr = descr;
                         this.quantity = quantity;                                              

                       }
```

Here is the repository definition:

```java
                    @Repository
                    public interface ProductRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Product,String> {

                    }
```

Here is what is saved to the repository, the productCode is not saved and a autogenerated ObjectId is provided instead:

```json
                  {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("63f511be4eaf1f75b27ff928"),       
                    "descr" : "Best in breed watches",
                    "quantity" :  122222                
                   }
```

Why is the provided productCode that I annotate with id and set in tbe constructor ignored? Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was missing the @PersistenceCreator annotation on the constructor